# Where we put language files of tesseract ocr engine in an android app?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm programming an application in android which uses OCR. I'm using the tesseract ocr and I want to ask where should I put the language files in my project, so that when I install my app in my phone(Samsung Galaxy S) the files be somewhere for the app to use them for the ocr process. I think that it should be in a place like: /mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata, but how this can be done without putting them myself in my device and let the installation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include the files with your project in the assets folder.

See [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to learn how to access your files from your activity. Also I would suggest that you don't copy them to the SDCard. Unfortunately since your files are going to have to be included with your project, and thus will be present in your apk file you're going to end up with a larger application size. But also unfortunately I don't believe that there is a way to delete the files from your apk at runtime, so even if you copy them over to the SD your app is still going to be the same size. For that reason I see no reason to copy them to the SD card, just access them from the AssetManager when you need to get them. Doing it that way also means that your application will not break if the SD card is removed / unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put them under Assets in a "tessdata" folder. That is in your project.
You can use Xamarin and the Tesseract for Xamarin nuget package, they're really easy to use, just bear in mind that you probably will have to install older version of the nugget if the latest version doesn't work. (2.10 was the working one as far as i remember)